# Do expressions have much to do with referential transparency?

Tags: programming-languages

In other words, can a programming language be referentially transparent even if not everything is an expression?

And can you say that if in a programming language, everything is an expression, then it is referentially transparent?

Comment: You should clarify what you mean by "expression" because there are many uses of the term. If you are unware of the many uses, then you should just tell us what programming language you have in mind (i.e, you know) and we will deduce what you're asking.

Comment: Also, "everything is not an expression" is probably not what you meant. Did you mean "not everything is an expression" by any chance?

Comment: By expression I just mean something that returns a value. I wasn't aware of the other uses of the term.

Comment: "everything is not an expression" - It's odd that I said that, since I had just read a post about that kind of wording in the English section of stackexchange. (All humans are not men != Not all humans are men). Well spotted.

Comment: Sorry, I still cannot pin it down. Do you mean "side-effect free" when you say "expression", i.e., no I/O, mutation of state, etc.?

Comment: I think my question is flawed then. I had assumed that if an expression had side effects then it wasn't a true expression, but yes I meant side effect free.

Comment: Algol-like languages define "expression" and "command" at a syntactic level, with the idea that expressions are side-effect free, and commands *may* cause side effects.

Answer (score 2):

I think the question is a bit poorly stated because it uses the term "expression" in an unclear way. So for the purposes of this answer let us say that an *expression* is a term which does not trigger any computational effects (such as divergence, I/O, mutation of state, exceptions, etc.). In Algol-like languages the opposite of expression is a *command*. I will say *term* for any piece of syntax.

I shall take *referential transparency* to mean that we may replace a term with its value without changing the program. More precisely, we obtain an observationally equivalent program when we replace the term with its value. Note however that referential transparency is *not* sensitive to *efficiency*, as replacing a term with its value almost always results in a more efficient program.

For example:

- `print "Hello, world!"` is not referentially transparent because it returns the unit value (`void` is a horrible, horrible misnomer because it suggests that *no value* is returned, when in fact the *trivial* value is returned; in contrast, raising an *exception* return no value) -- if we substitute the unit value, the program won't print anything anymore
- `x = x + 3` is not referentially transparent because it changes state (the value of `x`)
- `3 + 4` is referentially transparent because we may substitute it with `7` safely
- `while true do skip done` is an infinite loop, which is not referentially transparent. If we replace it just with `skip` (the unit value) then the program might do things it otherwise would not, such as launch missiles.

I hope you see now why your question is unclear. If you define "expression" as "free from all effects" then almost by definition it will be referentially transparent. If you define "expression" syntactically as "such and such syntactic forms are expressions", then we would have to check whether the syntax allows us to construct terms which are not referentially transparent.

One more point: it does not make sense to say that a programming language is referentially transparent, but rather that a particular term or a program is referentially transparent. So we should interpret the question from the first sentence as "if a programming language contains terms that trigger computational effects, must it have some non-transparent terms?", and I think then "yes" is the obvious answer because we just consider a command which triggers a computational effect.

You then ask about languages in which "everything is an expression". Well, that would be a *pure* language whose only possible effect is non-termination (because of infinite recursive calls). Depending on the language evaluation strategy this may or may not cause expressions to be referentially non-transparent. For example, in Haskell sometimes it does not matter that an expression is non-terminating because Haskell won't evaluate it until it is needed, which may be never. But in general non-termination is the thing to worry about in a pure language.

There are languages in which all terms are referentially transparent by design. Such languages cannot be Turing complete, however (assuming they have sane syntax). An example is Agda, which does not allow you to write a non-terminating expression, but it is still very powerful as a programming language, and a proof assistant.

A far more interesting question is whether a term can be referentially transparent even though it triggers computational effects. The answer is positive, and useful. Many data structures are self-modifying but they look referentially transparent from the outside, let me just mention splay trees as a famous example. Another example are caching strategies where lookups are cached (state change) so that they may be answered faster in the future. It is an interesting challenge for programming languages to properly account for such phenomena so that compilers can see what is going on and take advantage of the situation. For example, in a splay tree we may reorder lookups and updates, or if we work with two splay trees it does not matter which tree we work with first (so long as the data is not migrating between them). Note however.

I hope that answers your questions a bit by putting them into wider context.

Comment: I don't understand all of it but it's definitely useful. I can see now why complete referential transparency wouldn't be Turing complete.

Comment: You cannot possibly see that without proving the relevant theorem in computability theory.

Comment: I was merely going off of this sentence "There are languages in which all terms are referentially transparent by design. Such languages cannot be Turing complete, however (assuming they have sane syntax)." But obviously I don't understand any of this.

Comment: I think you perfectly understand the sentence, I am just saying that you should not think it is obviously true, because something needs to be proved there.

Comment: Can you give some explanation what is "the unit value"?  Why does the substitution of the unit value of the print function (1st example) cause "the program won't print anything anymore"? In the other hand, you consider skip to be the only unit value in 4st example. Why is not the loop effect regarded as "the unit value" there?

Comment: The `unit` type is the type whose only value is `()`, confusingly also called the unit. It corresponds to a one-element set. If you replace `print "Hello"` with `()` then you get the same result (namely `()`), but without printing.